# How to toggle only header element not the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this function that expands the `<ul>` and hides it after it is pressed.But when i press on `<li>` it will also close or expand. How do I make it to toggle only when the the `<h4>` is clicked ?

```
$('.category ul').hide();

$('.sub').click(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

```
<ul class="category text-center">
    <li class="sub">
        <h4><b>Licenses</b></h4>
        <ul class="archive_posts">
            <li class="posts"><a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Licence types and users plans</a></li>
            <li class="posts"><a href="#">Adding new licence</a></li>
            <li class="posts"><a href="#">Updating licence</a></li>
            <li class="posts"><a href="#">Removing licence</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change selector to `.sub h4`?

Comment: This seems like an extremely simple problem to solve. Did you try anything?

Comment: h4 has no Ul, wont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Changes made**

► changed `$('.sub').click(function() {` to `$('.sub h4')`

► changed `$(this).find('ul')` to `$(this).next()`

**Working Demo**

```js
 $('.category ul.archive_posts').hide();

 $('.sub h4').click(function() {
   $(this).next().slideToggle();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="category text-center">
  <li class="sub">
    <h4><b>Licenses</b></h4>
    <ul class="archive_posts">
      <li class="posts"><a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Licence types and users plans</a>
      </li>
      <li class="posts"><a href="#">Adding new licence</a>
      </li>
      <li class="posts"><a href="#">Updating licence</a>
      </li>
      <li class="posts"><a href="#">Removing licence</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the binding to the `h4`, then target the next `ul.archive_posts` for sliding.

```
$('.category ul').hide();
$('h4').click(function() {
    $(this).next('ul.archive_posts').slideToggle();
});
```

See it working in this JS Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/rwvdf8ys/1/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the `siblings('ul')` selector to find and close the neighbour ul. While `$(".sub h4")` limits the clickable elements to your `h4`.

```js
$('.category ul').hide();
$('.sub h4').click(function() {
  console.log('test');
  $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="category text-center">
  <li class="sub">
    <h4><b>Licenses</b></h4>
    <ul class="archive_posts">
      <li class="posts"><a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Licence types and users plans</a>
      </li>
      <li class="posts"><a href="#">Adding new licence</a>
      </li>
      <li class="posts"><a href="#">Updating licence</a>
      </li>
      <li class="posts"><a href="#">Removing licence</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$('li.sub h4').click(function() {
$(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is   $('this').find('ul').slideToggle();

'this' represents the obj that is cals the function. In this case it is h4. H4 has noe ul, so you cant find it. but you can find ul on $('.sub')

Here is ann example

```
$('.category ul').hide();

$('h4').click(function() {
    $('.sub').find('ul').slideToggle();
});


           <ul class="category text-center">
                <li class="sub">
                    <h4 id="foo"><b>Licenses</b></h4>
                    <ul class="archive_posts">
                        <li class="posts"><a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Licence types and users plans</a></li>
                        <li class="posts"><a href="#">Adding new licence</a></li>
                        <li class="posts"><a href="#">Updating licence</a></li>
                        <li class="posts"><a href="#">Removing licence</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

js fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/8hvc4cfh/